# Bootstrap tooltip doesn't hide when modal triggered if placement=body

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have a kendo grid which each row has an edit button. I am using Bootstrap to add a tooltip to the edit button, as well as other things. The edit button brings up a window to edit the attributes of the row model.

The tooltip kept getting cut off by the boundaries of the grid. To solve this I used placement=body when initializing the tooltips.

The problem I have now, is that the the tooltip does not hide if the button is clicked, and the editor window comes up. I tried changing the trigger to just be 'hover', but that did not help.

I tried doing ('[title]').tooltip('hide') in the edit event of the grid, but that doesn't seem to work at all.

I believe the problem has to do with 'edit' opening a kendo window. Because the other buttons with tooltips are fine, as they trigger a BootstrapDialog.

Comment: I'm having the same problem without Kendo-UI. My tooltip is displayed through the modal even with {trigger:'hover'} specified. Did you find a solution to your issue ?

Comment: no, it's a mess

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that the .tooltip has a z-index of 1070 while .modal has a z-index of 1050.

You can add the following to your css to ensure that .tooltip is displayed below .modal :

```
.modal{
  z-index: 1071;
}
```

Of course, this means that you absolutely can't have a tooltip displayed from *inside* your modal, so this maybe doesn't suit your specific needs.
If that's the case, you should be able to add another class to your tooltip div and override the z-index on this class.

I'm well aware of the monkey-patch nature of this fix, but I've looked for a solution for this for weeks and couldn't find anything better.